# Something like a latch function Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been trying to create a latch function using only excel formulas, no macro.

In cell H5 I have a number that changes from 0 to 1, and vice versa. The initial state of this number is 0. When it changes to 1, I want that other cell 'flag' this to me and keep this value independently if the H5 value returns to 0.

I tried to use the following formula:

```
=IF(H5=1;J5=1;0)
```

But with this code I keep getting the FALSE as response when the True Statement occurs.

Any ideia?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish that using a formula. Every time a sheet/book is calculated, all formulas are recalculated. Your only chance is using VBA.

Comment: You should use either `;` or `,` in your formula (depending on the language options), right now you're using one of each. but as iDevlop says, there is no way to do this with formulas alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to allow for circular references and iteration. Under:

***File>Options>Formulas***, set **Enable iterative calculation**.

[image]

In cell J5, put:

```
=IF(H5, 1, J5 )
```